# How to make program who will count how many stages are for pyramid?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my homework, don't understand anything how to write this program.

Make a program to calculate how many floors will be in the pyramid, if it is known to be built of square plates so that the top floor consists of one plate, the second floor from the top consists of 2 * 2 or 4 plates, the third floor from the top consists of 3 * 3 or 9 plates, etc. Read the number of plates (100 <= x <= 10000) from the input data.

Estimated number of floors as print a whole number on the output.

### Should look like this

Input data : 101 
 Output data : 6

Input data : 5353 
Output data : 24

Please help with this nightmare... 
p.s I think it should be done with loops, because we now learning about them.

Thanks everyone who will try to help, and have a nice day!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free do-my-homework service.

Comment: i know, i dont even ask for full solution, just mby some tips how to start, how i can at least put that interval from 100 to 10000? I dont even understand how to find solution in google..

Comment: Here, start from this: `int f; for ( f = 0; N > f * f; ++f, N -= f * f ); std::cout << f;` where `f` is floors and `N` number of plates.

Comment: @DimChtz appreciate your help, thanks a lot! Dont understand anything what happening there, but at least working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @DimChtz for help, mby someone will need some similar thing so there is code..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int f, N; /// f -- floors /// n -- number of plates
    cin >> N;
    for ( f = 0; N > f * f; ++f, N -= f * f );
    cout << f << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I dont understand anything what happening there, but the main thing its working..

[after compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G68Xi.png)